# XAMPP Retore Bulk Databases with CLI

Tags: mysql, database, xampp, mariadb, command-line-interface

On practice the way to retore MySQL or DBMaria Database from file "dump.sql" is this:

```
mysql --user=root --password="" --database=myblog < bitnami_wordpress.sql
```

But what do I do if they are multiple databases in File, any comand Line to upload this without pointing to a database?, becouse database is in Dump File like this:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `myblog `;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `myblog ` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
USE `myblog `;
```

i use PHPMyAdmin to crerate the `dump.sql file`; but i want to upload via CLI

Comment: If, as there appear to be, `USE` statements in this multi DB Backup. You can just forget the `--database` parameter and the code in the `.sql` file should manage putting the right tables in the right database and the right data in the right tables

Comment: if i forget `--database` parameter code willl look like this: `mysql --user=root --password=""` and i dont get updaload the file. How do you pass the file instruction without pointing to the database?

Comment: `mysql --user=root --password="" < bitnami_wordpress.sql`